# Acidity and structure of EDTA at different pH

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, titration

I was conducting complexometric titrations to measure the concentration of magnesium ions in my solution.
But of course, as EDTA is a chelating agent, knowing it’s structure and ionization form at different pH would be relevant.

Wikipedia lists 6 different pKa values for EDTA. What I was wondering is, as it has 4 carboxy groups, which all have pKa around 0-2.6, is how the other two pKa values come into effect (~6 and ~10 pKa).

Am I right in the assumption, that when EDTA is dissolved in water, the four carboxy groups release oxonium ions, which then could protonate the amino groups in intramolecular fashion? Or do the amino groups react themselves with water as a base? Basically, the EDTA structure after dissolving in water (pH ~3) would rather look like:

[image]

Then, if the pH is gradually increased to ~6, the first, then at ~10 the second amino group will be deprotonated?

As I said, I am quite unsure about the facts and any help or explanation of this structure at different pH levels would be appreciated.

Comment: The premise seems false. As of November 2012 [WP lists only the expected four pKa values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylenediaminetetraacetic_acid).

Comment: @OscarLanzi Curiously, the sidebar (which is presumably what you read) lists 4 pKa values, but the main text lists 6 (see the section on "coordination chemistry principles"). The main text also states which pKa belongs to which group, which seems like it should address OP's question. But I'm not convinced that the amino group has a lower pKa than the carboxyl groups, as it claims...

Comment: ... indeed, it seems like the Supporting Information of [Belle-Oudry, D. *J. Chem. Educ.* **2008,** *85* (9), 1269.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed085p1269) ([PDF link](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ed085p1269/suppl_file/jce2008p1269w.pdf)) has it the right way round. The first four pKa values (0 to 2) are the carboxyl groups; the 6 and 10 are the amino groups (technically they're pKa values of the protonated ammonium groups). Seems like somebody should edit that Wikipedia page.

Comment: @orthocresol IP user introduced this error about a month ago, fixed now.

Comment: So is what I said correct? Are the amino groups protonated due to the carboxy l groups, in addition to reacting with water as a base?